# Циклический скролл

Tags: unity3d, прокрутка, unity3d-ui

Нужно сделать циклический скролл, тоесть нужно, чтобы элементы перемещались с верхнего вниз при прокрутке скролла вниз и наоборот снизу вверх при прокрутке вверх, как бы создавая циклическую иллюзию. Контент имеет фиксированное количество элементов.
У меня задумка такая - проверяю скролл на движение и перемещаю элемент в зависимости от направления движения(вверх/вниз) -> перемещаю в коллекции с элементами меняя ссылки на первый и последний элемент и выставляю все элементы заново по контенту -> центрирую контент(пайвот контента 0.5, 0.5), так как если его не центрировать получится так, что можно будет докрутить до конца контента. Проблема в том, что:

1. Слишком большая скорость прокрутки нужно как-то сделать проверку на
   размер элемента, если крутить колесиком, то все отлично

Если есть вариант по лучше смело подсказывайте)

```
[SerializeField]
    private ScrollRect scrollRect;
    [SerializeField]
    private float spaceY;

    private RectTransform contentTransform;
    private LinkedList<RectTransform> contentElements;
    private int contentElementsCount;
    private Vector2 elementSizeDelta;
    private Vector2 startPosContent;

    private float preScrollVertNormalPos;

    private void Awake()
    {
        InitializeContent();
        AlignmentElements(true);
        this.startPosContent = this.contentTransform.anchoredPosition;
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if (this.scrollRect.verticalNormalizedPosition > this.preScrollVertNormalPos)
        {
            MoveLastElemToFirst();
            AlignmentElements();
        }
        else if (this.scrollRect.verticalNormalizedPosition == this.preScrollVertNormalPos)
        {
            return;
        }
        else if (this.scrollRect.verticalNormalizedPosition < this.preScrollVertNormalPos)
        {
            MoveFirstElemToLast();
            AlignmentElements();
        }

        this.preScrollVertNormalPos = this.scrollRect.verticalNormalizedPosition;
    }

    private void MoveFirstElemToLast()
    {
        RectTransform firstElem = this.contentElements.First.Value;

        this.contentElements.RemoveFirst();
        this.contentElements.AddLast(firstElem);
    }

    private void MoveLastElemToFirst()
    {
        RectTransform lastElem = this.contentElements.Last.Value;

        this.contentElements.RemoveLast();
        this.contentElements.AddFirst(lastElem);
    }

    private void InitializeContent()
    {
        this.contentTransform = GetComponent<RectTransform>();
        this.contentElements = new LinkedList<RectTransform>();
        foreach (RectTransform element in GetComponentsInChildren<RectTransform>())
        {
            this.contentElements.AddLast(element);
        }

        this.contentElements.RemoveFirst();

        this.contentElementsCount = this.contentElements.Count;
        this.elementSizeDelta = this.contentElements.First.Value.sizeDelta;

        this.contentTransform.pivot = new Vector2(0.5f, 0.5f);
        this.contentTransform.sizeDelta = new Vector2(this.contentTransform.sizeDelta.x, this.contentElementsCount * (this.elementSizeDelta.y + this.spaceY));
    }

    //Выравнивание элементов по контенту и центрирование контента
    private void AlignmentElements(bool initialize = false)
    {
        RectTransform prevElem = null;
        foreach (RectTransform element in this.contentElements)
        {
            if (initialize)
            {
                element.pivot = new Vector2(0.5f, 1f);
            }

            if (prevElem == null)
            {
                element.anchoredPosition = this.contentTransform.anchoredPosition + new Vector2(0, -this.spaceY);
            }
            else
            {
                element.anchoredPosition = prevElem.anchoredPosition + new Vector2(0, -(prevElem.sizeDelta.y + this.spaceY));
            }

            prevElem = element;
        }

        if (!initialize)
        {
            this.contentTransform.anchoredPosition = this.startPosContent;
        }
    }
```

UPD: Для ответа Ярослава
Попробовал реализовать, но элементы улетают в неизвестность. Почти наверняка не правильно вычисляю изменение скролла и скорей всего из-за этого дальше идут не правильные расчеты. Также взгляните, пж, на остальные расчеты мб я что-то упустил, сделал не так.

```
[SerializeField]
    private RectTransform content;

    private List<RectTransform> contentElements;
    private List<int> elementIndexes;

    private float scrollPosY;
    private Vector2 elementSizeDelta;

    private Vector2 prevScrollPos;
    private float totalElementsHeight;

    private void Awake()
    {
        this.contentElements = new List<RectTransform>();
        this.elementIndexes = new List<int>();
        this.scrollPosY = 0.5f;
        InitializeContent();
        prevScrollPos = Vector2.zero;
        this.totalElementsHeight = this.contentElements.Count * this.elementSizeDelta.y;
    }

    public void OnDrag(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        if (eventData.IsPointerMoving())
        {
            Vector2 delta = eventData.position - prevScrollPos;

            if (delta.y < 0)
            {
                this.scrollPosY += 0.1f;
            }
            else if (delta.y > 0)
            {
                this.scrollPosY -= 0.1f;
            }

            if (this.scrollPosY < 0f)
            {
                this.scrollPosY += 1f;
            }
            else if (this.scrollPosY > 1f)
            {
                this.scrollPosY -= 1f;
            }

            this.prevScrollPos = eventData.position;

            UpdateContent();
        }
    }

    private void UpdateContent()
    {
        int firstVisibleIndexElement = CalculateFirstVisibleIndexElement();
        float firstElementPosY = CalculateElementPosY(this.scrollPosY, firstVisibleIndexElement);
        int visibleElementsCount = CalculateVisibleElements();

        for (int i = 0; i < visibleElementsCount; i++)
        {
            if (firstVisibleIndexElement + i >= this.contentElements.Count)
            {
                this.elementIndexes.Add(firstVisibleIndexElement + i - this.contentElements.Count);
            }
            else
            {
                this.elementIndexes.Add(firstVisibleIndexElement + i);
            }
        }

        SetInactiveContentElements();
        SetActiveVisibleElements(firstElementPosY);
    }

    private int CalculateVisibleElements()
    {
        return Mathf.FloorToInt(this.content.sizeDelta.y / this.elementSizeDelta.y);
    }

    private int CalculateFirstVisibleIndexElement()
    {
        return Mathf.FloorToInt(this.contentElements.Count * this.scrollPosY);
    }

    private float CalculateElementPosY(float scrollPos, float indexElement)
    {
        return -this.elementSizeDelta.y * 0.5f - (this.totalElementsHeight * scrollPos - indexElement * this.elementSizeDelta.y);
    }

    private void SetInactiveContentElements()
    {
        foreach(RectTransform element in this.contentElements)
        {
            element.gameObject.SetActive(false);
        }
    }

    private void SetActiveVisibleElements(float firstVisibleElementPos)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < this.elementIndexes.Count; i++)
        {
            int indexElement = this.elementIndexes[i];
            Vector2 newElementPos = new Vector2(this.contentElements[indexElement].anchoredPosition.x, firstVisibleElementPos - i * this.elementSizeDelta.y);
            this.contentElements[indexElement].anchoredPosition = newElementPos;
            this.contentElements[indexElement].gameObject.SetActive(true);
        }
    }

    private void InitializeContent()
    {
        RectTransform[] contentElements = this.content.GetComponentsInChildren<RectTransform>();
        for (int i = 1; i < contentElements.Length; i++)
        {
            this.contentElements.Add(contentElements[i]);
        }

        this.elementSizeDelta = this.contentElements[0].sizeDelta;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Если список не огромен не обязательно постоянно добавлять и удалять новые элементы, можно просто сделать все элементы не активными и активировать только те, что должны быть видимы в фрейме.

1. Нужна переменная содержащая позицию скорла `Scroll` в диапазоне 0.0-1.0, прокручивании скролла `Scroll +=/-=`, после чего делаем его замкнутым `if (Scroll > 1) Scroll -= 1f; if (Scroll < 0) Scroll += 1f;`.
2. Затем пишем единственную функцию обрабатывающую значение `Scroll`. По общей высоте всех элементов списка и значению `Scroll` находим `index` элемента который будет сверху окна списка и его позицию `yPos`. Затем исходя из размеров окна списка и размеров элемента `elementHeight` списка определяем сколько элементов мы видим в данный момент `elementOnFrame` (хотя оно не меняется и можно определить всего 1 раз). Делаем список индесов `for (int i = 0 i < elementOnFrame; i++)` элементов попадающих в фрейм, начиная с найденного `index`, если `index+i >= ElementList.Count` то `Add(index+i-ElementList.Count)`. Делаем все элементы не активными. Далее элементы по составленному списку индексов активными и располагаем `y = yPos-i*elementHeight`.

И становится не важно какая скорость прокрутки. Написанная функция отображает любую позицию списка согласно `Scroll` в не зависимости от всего.

Comment: В общем идею понял, не совсем понятно только с высчитыванием индекса первого видимого элемента и позицией скролла. "прокручивании скролла Scroll +=/-=, По общей высоте всех элементов списка и значению Scroll находим index элемента" - можно подробней?

Comment: `Scroll` просто `float` в диапазоне 0-1. `index = Mathf.Mathf.FloorToInt(List.Count*Scroll)`. А `yPos` что-то вроде  `-elementHeight*0.5f-(TotalHeight*Scroll-index*elementHeight)`.

Comment: дополнил ответ, взгляните пожалуйста.